# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'executing_eagerly'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Hello everyone I am new to machine learning, and I am attempting to build a custom object detection model on the CPU. However, I am getting this error below after I type:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ -pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config.
```

Any input would be most appreciated. My path has been config but the problem occurs the seem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Thremane\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\Thremane\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 136, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "C:\Users\Thremane\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py", line 304, in train
    train_config.optimizer)
  File "C:\Users\Thremane\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\builders\optimizer_builder.py", line 45, in build
    global_step=global_step)
  File "C:\Users\Thremane\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\builders\optimizer_builder.py", line 113, in _create_learning_rate
    staircase=config.staircase)
  File "C:\Users\Thremane\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\utils\learning_schedules.py", line 79, in exponential_decay_with_burnin
    if tf.executing_eagerly():
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'executing_eagerly'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. The version of TensorFlow and the pre-train model must be compatible. I installed Tensorflow v1.5 in my environment and the appropriate comit package. Now I’m training my model.